# Show activity indicator while changing views (Segue) and load data for next view (API)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Umm I really need some help
I have a search view, when user clicks the cell (basically a game), the view changes to a Game View. Atm I was not using any async stuff so while the game view loads, the app kinda hangs for 2-3 secs on the search view after clicking the cell (since the viewDidLoad method of game view loads all data from web API)

What I wanted to do was when a user clicks game in searchView, the gameView instantly shows up with just a blank view and a Activity Indicator meanwhile the data is fetched from API.
Once data is fetched, the gameView (which is a tableView btw) reloads the data and shows it accordingly from the fetched data.

If it makes any diff. I am using static cells for gameView and thus not using cellAtRowIndex code.

I have attached images for some of my methods I tried to use as per my searching on SO for AFNetworking, async etc etc.

The table IB elements are filled from data in a separate function showGame, I am calling this function in rowsForSection since table will be reloaded after block completion. Excuse me but I wasnt sure what would be the best way to reload table or rather show the data.

Atm my app is showing me my default static content which I created in interface builder (and with only 1 row). AKA the table is not being updated. I used breakpoints to check and yeah the showGame is getting correct data, passing correct data to IB elements. Even the execution is reaching the point in code to return 5/6 rows BUT the actual app/view is not updating properly.

[image: the function to fetch the game from my API and store it in a property array]

[image: The table IB elements are filled from data in a separate function showGame, I am calling this function in rowsForSection since table will be reloaded after block completion.]

---

For those who want pastebin text code, here it is:

.m file where async code to fetch game from API is
http://pastebin.com/p2FETbku

.m file of my gameView class/tableView which shows the table view and data, this file also has the showGame method to show the game data fetched from above class
http://pastebin.com/cWtSKPw0

**Please excuse my code or any small mistakes, I am still in learning phase and just started 3 weeks ago.**

---

The static cells were working fine before I was using async method, somehow its getting messed up during/after that reloaddata

Comment: It would be better to copy and paste your code, not an image of your code. Also, make it clear what code blocks are in which controller.

Comment: @rdelmar added pastebin text code, hope the controllers are understandable by the desc above snippets

Comment: AFAIK, static table views are just that -- static. I don't think you can change the number of rows or sections (only the content in the cells you created in IB). You shouldn't be implementing any of the data source methods, like numberOfRowsInSection. You probably need to use a table with dynamic prototype cells.

Comment: erm I need to dynamically control rowsinsection and even in static it do works :| I was using it early when not using this async stuff and was working perfect (as mentioned in my post)

Comment: Well, it may work, but that's not the way Apple says to implement static table views. In any case, I don't know how to do that, and I don't see the point of using a static table view when you want dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

One point that I think you are missing is that execution of this statement

```
GDgameViewController *gdv = [[GDgameViewController alloc] init];
```

doesn't return the tableViewController hence the tableView that is currently presented.

So in your function   `+(void) fetchGame:(NSString *)gid` what you are reloading is the tableView that is not presented.
To help you further I have created a project for you which use a bit different approach to do your work but it does it optimally. You can find project [here](https://github.com/aMother/tableViewMess.git). If you don't know how to use gitHub, don't worry just download the zip file[image: Image Showing From Where]. Please make this count as

Comment: ofc I know how to use git atleast :/ I will test your demo code today and let you know if it was what I wanted to do or helps me, thanks for the detailed example code

Comment: @vongolashu Does it help you. Let me know if something broke in project

Comment: sorry for taking a day to reply, had some issues at home, anyway, running your project as it is after unzipping is giving quite a lot of errors, basically its not recognizing your custom classes while using them as Type for property. Do you have skype or steamviewer to remote my screen and see my/your project ? I did get the idea of how you are doing it, but since cant run it to see its workflow, a bit hard for a newbie like me to do it within my own project.

Comment: Btw if I am correct, your general idea is to make a "Loading" screen View separately and have the push segue push to it, then in BG when the AI is loaded, have it retrieve data from API, when done, push the view to the Game View controller/scene ?

Comment: Yes this was my idea. I know there are errors in the project. You have to re-write the fetch method as well as link project with the external networking framework you are using. Once you rewrite it, errors will blow away. The workflow of the project is mentioned in README.md. So, read it carefully. If still problems persist after rewriting the method, just send me the zip of your project or suggest changes through github.

Comment: ye I got that, understood your idea aswell and damn this seems way too neat and better thing to do than what I was trying. I will try this tonight in my actual project, but one thing I wanted to ask. Can I just make one AI view and use it for any and all other views (even the ones using different navigation controllers). How will the storyboard view flow look if I want to use one common AI view ?

Comment: What AI stands for ? And if this project helped you don't feel shy to accept the answer as it will help others...

Comment: Yeah will upvote it and accept once I confirm what you said is possible :P And AI I mean Activity Indicator, btw is what I asked in previous comment possible ? Having only one common AI view and using it for any and all views which needs async loading, and how will its storyboard flow/structure look like ?

Comment: tested code, its getting crashed at the 2nd segue block to manually push the segue. The segue identifier in code and in storyboard identity is same, error <GDmainTableViewController: 0x8d87db0>) has no segue with identifier 'viewGame''

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42149/discussion-between-vongolashu-and-amother)

Comment: Yes a common AI possible. You can use polymorphism for that. I would recommend you to not to get overambitious with it and concentrate on the core of your project. And try to resolve errors yourself as they will teach you a lot. if even after trying code breaks, send me zip file at to.nurture@outlook.com or suggest changes through github...

Comment: well I used your method, ofc replaced code and stuff with my own as needed, but I am still not able to get past that 2nd segue call. As I mentioned above I am getting that error even though the second segue identifier is same.

Comment: Ok, send me the zip of your project... to  to.nurture@outlook.com. I will try my best to debug it

Comment: erm it wont be possible for me to send the project due to the privacy and nature of project as well as the API and some confidential logins the code has (to make full app work), I do can send related .h .m files which are related to question but they are already linked in the question itself. I am not too sure but I think this segue identifier not found is related to code of 2nd block segue or prepareforseguewithidentifier

Comment: Read viewController programming guide. It will really help you